# can we ignore a line in json parsing?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I get a json  of below type from a rest service and I need ot parse it and get data through it. This json is an invalid in terms of Json format, but is there way to parse this or ignore a line which has comma

```
{
 "yshan" : "EMP",
    "yuansshi" : "EMP",
    "zacharyb" : "EMP",
    "zholin" : "EMP",
    "fy16interns_bxb" : {,
        "avaderiy" : "EMP",
        "crellis" : "EMP",
    }
}
```

My main intention is to get all the "key" field names which has the value "EMP" whether they are nested or regular json?

I used jsonnode and jsonNode.getFields() for retrieval. This works fine for the json which dont have nested elements, but for the one's which have nested elements it throws "unexpected character" error like

```
Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name
```

If you can help me out, it would be appreciable

Comment: It's not valid JSON, so it can't be parsed using a deserializer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes, I know its not a valid JSON, but what would be the better format to get these kinds of information or is there a chance to ignore a line or few lines while parsing the json?

Comment: Maybe you could try to get the `"fy16interns_bxb"` value as a plain String, not an object

Comment: Ideally you fix the server or contact the person responsible for the poorly constructed API

Comment: but is it possible to get only such lines as plaintext and other lines of json as json objects

Comment: Why don't you do the right, obvious thing: fixing the JSON?

Comment: ok thanks for your response. Let me wait for few more responses or ideas and close the question

Comment: As you've said `jsonNode.getFields()` works, though that is surprising to me because I would think that `jsonNode` can't be constructed without valid JSON from the start

Comment: @JBNizet: I am only receiving the JSON, so I just want to make sure what all I can do at my end. and if problem can be solved from my end, I want to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the line would result in even worse json.

If the error is always the same, maybe like it's always a curly bracket followed by a comma, then you could try

1. read the json response in a string
2. clean up the string (example: `json.replace("{,", "{")`)
3. parse the cleaned string.

Of course: only if fixing the API is impossible and parsing the 'patched' response makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have made a fix to API so that i get a valid JSON. Now the problem is solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract keys where value is `"EMP"`, you can use regex:

```
"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*"EMP"
```

As Java code, that would be:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"\\s*:\\s*\"EMP\"").matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pPWWSI/1).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have made a fix to API so that i get a valid JSON. Now the problem is solved. thanks